# What can a wife call her husband's other wife in polygynous societies?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am aware that two wives of the same man can be named co-wives. But what can a wife call her husband's other wife? I think calling her my co-wife will not be correct.

Comment: Did you look up "co-wife"? If, after that, it's still not the word you're looking for please explain why.

Comment: So do you mean you find it natural that a wife calls her husband's other wife "my co-wfie" If yes then this is what I am asking for.

Comment: I don't live in a polygamous society, so I'm just going based off what I read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***Sister wife***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sister_wife).

> (in a polygamous society) any of the women married to the same man.
>   *‘her mother and her sister wives live in different homes’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sister_wife

Comment: As an additional reference, there's a TV show on TLC since 2010 called *Sister Wives* about a polygamous family https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_Wives